# Android ListView: Is it possible to add data to a few rows before-wards, while the rest of the ListView is loaded dynamically?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I want to create a `ListView` having the same row layout for all the rows except the last two. Likewise I want to populate all the rows from the same `ArrayList` of objects of a class named `MyDataClass`, except the last two rows.

For the last two rows: I want the second last row to have a `Button`, and the last row to have an `ImageView` only.

**This has two parts: (a) Add all the data to be displayed in the `ListView` to the `ListView`'s datasource (the `ArrayList` here).** (b) Inside `getView`, do something like:

```
@Override   
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
         .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     if (position == arrayList.size()-2 )
        xml_type = R.layout.row_imageView
     else if (position == arrayList.size()-1 )
         xml_type = R.layout.row_button
     else
         xml_type = R.layout.row_normal

     View rowView = inflater.inflate(xml_type, parent, false);
}
```

Now the question is from (a): If the image and the button were something I was adding to every row, it would probably make sense to make the image and the button fields of the `MyDataClass` objects, but they are just one image, and one button, which need to be added to the last two rows.

**So is there a way to use difference datasets/data sources for different rows?**

**Or better yet, is it possible to set data to the last two rows before-wards while the rest of the `ListView` is populated dynamically?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a list footer, there's the possibility to add a footer view to the ListView using `addFooterView`.

The [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addFooterView%28android.view.View%29) says:

> `public void addFooterView (View v)`
>
> Add a fixed view to appear at the bottom of the list. If addFooterView is called more than once, the views will appear in the order they were added. Views added using this call can take focus if they want.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      // grab your list
      ListView  list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

      // grab a layout inflater
      LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      // inflate the image row layout 
      ImageView footerImage = (ImageView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_footer_image, null);  
      
      // .. maybe change the image here, bind click listener - whatever
 
      // add the footer image to the listview
      list.addFooterView(footerImage);          

      // inflate the layout for the button row
      Button footerButton = (Button)inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_footer_button, null);  
      
      // bind a click listener
      footerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          // user has clicked the button in the footer, do something
        }
      });

      // add footer button to the list view
      list.addFooterView(footer);

      // ... populate your list with the adapter as usual
  }
}
```

**layout/list_footer_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/your_image"/>
```

**layout/list_footer_button.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
  android:id="@+id/button"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Click me!"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` only displays the rows that are visible, and it will do so very quickly. If the data is not available, then it will wait to display until the data is available.

The problem is that you need to background load your data so that the `ListView` does not delay displaying what it already has. If you have placeholders or other static content or easy to display options, then the `ListView` will perform like you want it to.